# Using Jigoshop, how can I add a custom post type to the cart via code?

Tags: e-commerce, jigoshop

I want to programmatically add an item to the cart, and that item is not a product.. It's a custom post type that I am creating. I think I'm going in the right direction by using the Jigoshop cart class. Found in the jigoshop folder under classes/jigoshop_cart.class.php. The problem is that I'm not sure exactly how to hook something into it that is not a product.. I thought maybe someone could point me the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to sell access to premium content? The logic and goal escape me.

Comment: Is there another way around what I'm trying to do, yes.. However that's not very elegant and I want to accomplish it this way. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't answer my question, nor is your OP very clear. So there's little I can offer for suggestions.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to sell premium content. I want to make my own post types with a price value of my own, and then direct the new CPT item to the cart for checkout. If this is unrealistic, or not doable, that's fine, I'll work around it.

Comment: Like just about anything with code it's certainly doable given enough time and effort. But unless you have exceptional requirements that you're not posting in you question it just doesn't make sense. It sounds as if your trying write something custom that's already done in any e-commerce platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **You can't.**

Long answer: Jigoshop is designed to only allow checkout of our "product" CPT.

In reality, you should have been looking at Jigoshop's template_functions.php file which has our add to cart functions. For security reasons, Jigoshop has checks, absolutely everywhere that the CPT is in fact Jigoshop's own product CPT.

Source: I'm a Core Developer at Jigoshop (it doesn't get more official than this)

Comment: Ok, thank you for that complete answer. I did find a work around for what I'm trying to do, but I will award you the reputation points for this, I appreciate it.

Comment: Not a problem :).